# Firebug freezes Firefox on showing errors from FirePHP

Tags: php, firefox-addon, firebug, firephp

I have problem with debugging one of my projects. Every notice/warning/error is caught by **FirePHP**, and set with headers to browser. I catch all those errors with enabled **Firebug**, and everything's showing right in console:

[image]

One of function of FirePHP with Firebug is to show details about those errors. And here's the problem - when i hover error with my mouse, Firefox freezes. CPU usage is very low, **but memory consumption rises to 1,5-2GB**. Cure is to kill FF, or wait 3-5 minutes till it suggests to kill frozen script

> chrome://firephp/content/viewer/panel.js:601

[image]

Do anyone struggles with similar issue?

**Versions:**

- Firefox 36.0.1
- Firebug 2.0.8
- FirePHP 0.7.4

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so i found why is it freezing. Data sent to Firebug contains all i18n messages from my app (as i'm using SF1.0 - it is in context) - and it simply is too large to quickly parse it to viewer. I dug up into my code, and even disabling sending all context from my PHP, doesn't disable context to show up in **Variable viewer**.

Comment: It appears that this might be more appropriate to ask on the [FirePHP support site](http://forum.firephp.org/). That should provide a more focused audience.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but I would try (for a test) disabling firePHP and use instead a logging tool such as log4php and have it log your exceptions where and when they might be thrown.

Thus, if you're not doing so already.. use try and catch blocks and in the catch blocks, log your exception to a file that you'd declare in the config/instantiation of log4php.

Just a suggestion.